# JAXB binding simple types

Tags: binding, jaxb

I'm trying to generate classes from an xsd but I'm getting the following exception when trying to customize a simple type:

```
    com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: A type safe enum customization is specified to a simple type that cannot be mapped to a type safe enum.
```

The declaration of the simple type that throws the exception is as follows:

```
    <xs:simpleType name="BroadcastAlertsItem">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
        reserved (0)
        broadcastAlertsAccepted (1)
        broadcastAlertsNotAccepted (2)
     </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:union>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedInt">
                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                <xs:maxInclusive value="2"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="reserved"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="broadcastAlertsAccepted"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="broadcastAlertsNotAccepted"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And this is the binding from the binding customization file:

```
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='BroadcastAlertsItem']">
        <jaxb:typesafeEnumBase name="BroadcastAlertsItem">
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="reserved"/>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="broadcastAlertsAccepted"/>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="broadcastAlertsNotAccepted"/>
        </jaxb:typesafeEnumBase>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

As you will suppose, I have tried many more ways to achieve this goal :(

Does anybody know if there is a way to bind that simple type without modifying the xsd file?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You demand too much from JAXB. For the union of simple types what JAXB should do: create `enum` per union part or for the whole union? Also `xs:unsignedInt`-based restriction are not mappable to Java enums (they are numbers, not strings; what if base is signed int? what if upper value goes beyond MAX_INT?) In your case I would split the union into two simple types, at least one is mappable to Java.

Comment: I appreciate very much your help. 
I'm pretty sure that modifying the simpletype definition may solve the problem but the xsd file shall not be modified since it is a third party standard schema.